# 自作アルバムの動画をAVPlayerで再生するとsignal SIGABRT発生（iPad）

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

初めて投稿します。swiftでiOSアプリを作成していますが詰まってしまいました。

自作のアルバムに保持している動画ファイルをAVPlayer(AVPlayerViewController)を用いて再生するとsignal SIGABRTが発生して落ちてしまいます。
UICollectionViewを用いて、自作アルバムのAssetを表示→cellを選択したものが動画であればAVPlayerで再生するという動作です。
初めての再生は問題なく動くのですが、再度再生させようとすると落ちます。
iPhone6では発生せず、iPadでのみ問題発生します。

原因を探っているのですが見つかりません。
なにか情報等いただけたら幸いです。

```
var avPlayerViewController:AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath:IndexPath)
{
    let selectAsset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
    if selectAsset.mediaType == .video
    {
        phImageManager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: selectAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(playerItem, info) -> Void in
            let playerItem = playerItem
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = player
            self.avPlayerViewController.delegate = self
            self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated:true, completion:{
                self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
            })    // Thread 11: signal SIGABRT発生
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: 一晩経って確認したところ、以下のwarningが発生していました。
Comparing non-optional value of type 'AVPlayer' to nil always returns false.
発生箇所は
self.avPlayerViewController.player = player
です。

Comment: 追記です。全ソースコードでstoryboardは使用していません。
落ちるとき、コンソールには、"libc++abi.dylib: tarminating with uncaught exception of type ESException"と表示されます。

Comment: @tacheyyさん コードを見やすくしていただきありがとうございました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
UICollectionViewを持つ画面①(親クラス：UIViewController)とは別クラスの画面②(親クラス：UIViewController)を生成、画面②でAVPlayerViewControllerを持つように変更しました。
※AVPlayerViewControllerを継承したクラス生成が禁じられているようなのでUIViewControllerで対応
再生時間やコントローラー、シークバーなどの不具合が起きなくなりました。
今のところ落ちたりもしていません。
画面①：ViewControllerOne
画面②：ViewControllerTwo

画面①（一部）　ViewControllerOneクラス

```
var avPlayerViewController:ViewControllerTwo = ViewControllerTwo()

(省略)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let selectAsset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
    // 動画のときの処理
    phImageManager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: selectAsset, options: nil, requestHandler:{(playerItem, info) -> Void in
        self.avPlayerController.initItem(item: playerItem!)
        self.present(self.avPlayerController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    })
}
```

画面②（一部） ViewControllerTwoクラス

```
var avPlayerController: AVPlayerViewController?
var player:AVPlayer?
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

(省略)

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    avPlayerController?.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.addChildViewController(avPlayerController!)
    self.view.addSubview((avPlayerController?.view)!)
    self.avPlayerController?.player?.play()
}

func initItem(item:AVPlayerItem)
{
    playerItem = item
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avPlayerController?.player = player
}
```

Answer (score 0):

以下に変更したところ、signal SIGABRTは発生しなくなり落ちなくはなりました。
※ただし、繰り返しcellの選択→再生→Doneで一覧に戻ると、２回目以降の再生でコントローラーのseekbarと再生時間がおかしくなってしまいます。（前の時間情報が残ったまま？）

```
var avplayerViewController:AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath:IndexPath)
{
    let selectAsset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)
    if selectAsset.mediaType == .video
    {
        let player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()    // requestPlayerItemから外に出しました
        phImageManager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: selectAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(playerItem, info) -> Void in
// 取得したplayerItemをそのまま使用するように変更（変更前）
//        let playerItem = playerItem
//        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
// playerのcurrent itemとしてplayerItemを置き換え（変更後）
            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = player

//        self.avPlayerViewController.delegate = self    ←特に理由は無いが削除

// presentのcompletionを使用しないように変更（変更前）
//        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated:true, completion:{
//            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
//        })    // Thread 11: signal SIGABRT発生
        })
// completionをnilへ変更、requestPlayerItemから外に出しました（変更後）
        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        player.play()
    }
```

落ちなくなった代わりに、再生時間やシークバーの不具合、一時停止ボタンが表示しなくなるなど他の問題があります。UICollectionViewや別画面でナビゲーションコントローラーを使用しているので、どこが要因なのか判別し難いです。